# Why use both a BJT and a MOSFET for switching a subcircuit?

Tags: bjt, mosfet-driver

I have seen a BJT used together with a MOSFET for a power switching in an actual circuit.

[image: Schematic for switching using both a BJT and a MOSFET]

Below the **ON** voltages I have indicated the **OFF** voltages in red color.

What is the reason behind using such a configuration?
What is the advantage of this compared to just using a single BJT or MOSFET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as you say, a very common setup.
The reason for adding the BJT is in order to drive the MOSFET with proper gate voltage.

In the schematic shown, the P-MOSFET need 9V at its gate in order to fully shut off. If you would connect that straight to the 3.3 or 5 V GPIO of some MCU, you will never be able to turn off the MOSFET.

When used with a low-side switch, it is often that the MOSFET requires higher gate voltage to saturate than what can be provided from the GPIO controlling it. Common power N-MOSFET's often need like 7-10 Vgs to fully open.

If the MOSFET is replaced by a power BJT, many times the base current needed is higher than what the GPIO can supply so you need extra driving circuitry. Or for the high side switch case, you have just the same voltage issue as with MOSFET.

An additional feature of this extra transistor is that it inverts the signal. So with this setup, `1` in turns the load on, `0` in turns the load off. Otherwise, it is the opposite.