# Gate of Logic level MOSFET connect to Esp32 gpio

Tags: mosfet, switching, esp32, logic-level, sim800

I want to use [IRLR024N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlr024npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356694f7f265d) logic MOSFET to switch on/off a Sim800L module. This module consume 2A for 500μs and then consume only 200mA. I supply this module with 4V. This MOSFET able to switch on this module if I connect its Gate to an Esp32  gpio with resistor?

Comment: Should work, but I'd think twice before using a low-side switch for something like this.

Comment: You are right. I wanted to buy P-channel logic level MOSFET, but unfortunately in my country not available now.

Comment: In my case p mosfet is not a good solution I think. In off state the gate is 3,3 volt and the source is 4 volt. The Vgs=0.7 volt so will flow current because the Vgs is not 0V.

Comment: That's easily solved with a second transistor. See here for example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/606733/why-use-both-a-bjt-and-a-mosfet-for-switching-a-subcircuit